# Windows 10 BitLocker unable to set startup password

Tags: windows-10, bitlocker, windows-10-v1607

I'm running windows 10 pro ver. 1607 on a PC with TPM 2.0 chip.
I've enabled BitLocker, but am unable to set a startup password for it - there is no such option on the BitLocker settings screen:

[image: screenshot]

There is also no settings for BitLocker in the group policy editor:

[image: screenshot]

I found no information about this on the microsoft pages. Does anyone know what to do to enable this?

Thank you.

Comment: Is this a standalone or domain-joined machine?

Comment: It is a Standalone computer.